# Tell Xcode 4 to ignore some targets of a scheme?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, xcode4

I want Xcode to ignore some targets for now, both when building and when looking for issues as I edit.  How do I tell it to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the active scheme, select its Build action from the left-hand list, then uncheck the checkboxes corresponding to each action you *don't* want that target to be built for.